# mongo command not working after logging into kubernetes pod

Tags: python, mongodb, kubernetes, flask, google-kubernetes-engine

I wanted to check my mongo database, not sure which database my application is putting the data. Basically i have configured a very simple tasks application using a python flask api(deployed in gke) which in turn connects to a mongo database in the same gke cluster. The application works fine.
I referred to this link
[link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-your-first-flask-mongodb-app-on-kubernetes-8f5a33fa43b4)

Below is my application yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tasksapp
  labels:
    app: tasksapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tasksapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tasksapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: tasksapp
          image: myimage/1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

The python code section which connects to the database --->This does not have username /password. Not sure which database it is connecting to(even though in the code it says as 'dev'. This is why I wanted to check the mongo db pod.

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import socket
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://mongo:27017/dev"
mongo = PyMongo(app)
db = mongo.db
@app.route("/")
def index():
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    return jsonify(
        message="Welcome to Tasks app! I am running inside {} pod!".format(hostname)
    )
```

the mongo db deployment yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: storage
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mongo-pvc
```

the issue is that when i log into the pod for mongo, mongo command is not recognized as shown below?

```
kubectl exec -it mongo-869f6488c8-jnkgp -- /bin/bash
root@mongo-869f6488c8-jnkgp:/# cd home
root@mongo-869f6488c8-jnkgp:/home# ls
root@mongo-869f6488c8-jnkgp:/home# mongo
bash: mongo: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deployment does not specify an image tag so will run the latest version of mongo (currently v6).

v6 mongo does not include this legacy `mongo` shell; it has been replaced with `mongosh`

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash mongo
root@e920eac138d7:/# mongo
bash: mongo: command not found
root@e920eac138d7:/# mongosh --nodb
Current Mongosh Log ID: 648ce23ff5d64ce445218977
Using Mongosh:          1.10.0

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/


To help improve our products, anonymous usage data is collected and sent to MongoDB periodically (https://www.mongodb.com/legal/privacy-policy).
You can opt-out by running the disableTelemetry() command.
```

Notwithstanding this, the points that [Ernani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76493330/10490683) makes are also relevant.

Comment: Thanks, I believe dev database is created by the python code itself? Or is it there by default like admin, test, local?

Comment: The default database is test if you don't specify otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, it is not advisable to run MongoDB as a `Deployment`, also some folks do refrain using Stateful apps in Kubernetes in general such as Databases because it can lead into many problems and it is a hard thing to manage. Some managed services really helps such as Atlas for MongoDB.

Considering this environment is for **testing purposes** or **self managed**, I'd run Mongo using either a helm chart **(when in dev mode)** such as [Bitnami's](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/mongodb/#installing-the-chart) or a more elegant and advanced Operator such as [MongoDB Community Operator](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator) **(while in Production and if I really know what I am doing and care for retain mode of PVCs, constant backups, etc.)**

Aside from this, to your actual use case, it depends on the `namespace` you are deploying your app and Mongo's `StatefulSet/Deployment/Pod`.

If you are just deploying it in the `default` namespace, make sure to point the hostname of your Mongodb in your Python app to  `<mongodb-svcname>.default.svc.cluster.local` on MongoDB's port, normally defaults to `27017`

So, again, if your Service is called `mongodb-svc`, in order for your Python app to be able to connect to it you'd use then `mongodb-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:27017` as a valid hostname for it.

Make sure to match both `<service-name>` and `<namespace>` and don't forget the **Port** as well